# Facebook like button "Internal server error"

Tags: facebook

Good morning!

I've been testing the Facebook like button by default and I got a recurring error, I've followed the example code from the official site and tried the 2 options, iframe and the other, with booth I got the same error

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h1>button1</h1>
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fnoudiari.es&width=93&layout=box_count&action=like&size=large&show_faces=false&share=false&height=65&appId" width="93" height="65" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>



<h1>button2</h1>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7&appId=YOURAPPID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/noudiari.es" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help with this?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

it seems to work for me. Do you have a sample of the page you are using it on ?

Comment: You can test it here: http://www.infinitel.es/test.html, if you click on like it looks like it works but its not. If you check with firebug you got this error: "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like/connect?dpr=1"

I've already tested a button on another page or the section in facebook developer plugins and also got the same error.

I've also tried to change the facebook fan page to like.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like due to all my attempts facebook blocked my account, I tried with another and worked fine.

Thanks